# Для чего нужен тип хранения long long и как его использовать в коде Python. Порядок действий в подобных неясных ситуациях

Tags: python

**Проблема:** в задании на сайте Фоксфорд дана задача, где в результате решения может получиться очень большое число. В подсказке к задаче сказано: "может произойти переполнение 32-битной целочисленной переменной. Для хранения ответа нужно использовать тип long long."

Какая именно задача - не важно, подобный комментарий может быть и к другой задаче.

**Вопрос:** для чего нужен тип хранения long long и как его использовать в коде Python? Желательно указать ход действий, чтобы можно было правильно действовать в данном случае.

Comment: Просто у меня в задаче встретилось вот это "Для хранения ответа нужно использовать тип long long."

Comment: В задаче Python?? Ссылку дайте, поясню с учетом того, что увижу там. Но все, что выше я написал, все равно остается:-)

Comment: и я не понял через Google

Comment: https://foxford.ru/lessons/83261/tasks/18457

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137872/discussion-between--and-user504877).

Comment: Почитайте здесь про типы данных в c++. Именно там есть long long https://metanit.com/cpp/tutorial/2.3.php

А в питоне аналог есть в библиотеке ctypes. 
from ctypes import c_longlong

Comment: @Alpensin, вы точно уверены, что школьнику в задаче внезапно такое требование выдвинули?

Comment: самая последняя строка

Comment: @Сергей Я по вопросу ориентируюсь. Да и ему будет полезно ознакомиться с тем, какие типы данных бывают) По ссылке довольно простое описание.

Comment: @Alpensin, разумеется полезно:-) Еще полезнее самому найти, человек, вроде, неглупый.

Comment: При решении данной задачи на Python не нужно использовать именно long long, достаточно просто int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раз уж начал с общего, то напишу тут, чтобы комментарии не множить, да и полезно будет, надеюсь.

Самое главное в обучении - научиться учиться самостоятельно и задавать правильные вопросы.

В данном случае логика действий человека, учащегося относительно самостоятельно и желающего учиться ещё лучше (а потом хорошо работать и хорошо зарабатывать интеллектуальным трудом) должна была быть следующей:

1. Обнаружена непонятная запись. С имеющимися знаниями по Python не стыкуется никак.
2. Набирается в Google / Yandex текст "long long". Обнаруживается, что масса ссылок идёт на C++ или C. И практически ничего на Python.
3. Бегло читается в С++, что это и зачем, становится ясно, что это тип данных для хранения очень больших чисел.
4. Перечитывается на всякий случай глава учебника (в идеале - документация) по типам данных в Python и становится понятно, что этого типа данных нет в нем, как минимум, в версии 3.х., где о любых самых длинных числах язык заботится сам.
5. Делается предположение, что наиболее вероятны следующие варианты:

a) обучающийся попал не в свой курс (не туда зашел сбой на сайте и т.д.). Проверяется, так ли это.

б) ошибка в условии задачи, оставшаяся после copy/paste авторами курса c задачи на другом языке или с какой-то древней версии Python (если там в 2.х. вообще такое было). Если есть у кого ответственного за курс спросить - он или она и спрашивается (вариант: обсуждается на форуме данной задачи), если нет - принимается за наиболее вероятный случай. Задача решается без этого условия.
Опционально: задаётся вопрос на SO, но с уже собранными деталями и своим предположением.

в) зачем-то авторы хотят, чтобы этот тип был использован. Начать изучать данную версию, только если задача не будет никак приниматься. Держим для этого в уме комментарий @Alpensin про "в питоне аналог есть в библиотеке ctypes. from ctypes import c_longlong" (а также, что "Модуль ctypes представляет собой совместимые с языком C типы данных и позволяет вызывать функции в библиотеках DLL или совместно используемых библиотеках. " , т.е. что в этой задаче он непонятно зачем нужен).

Дополнительно: помним, что когда начнем работать, нам начальство или Заказчики будут периодически ставить достаточно бредовые задачи (иногда и учителя в школе, или преподаватели в универе). Большая ошибка - пытаться их выполнить любой ценой. Надо самому покопаться и вернуться к постановщику задачи с вопросами, если видно, что что-то не так.